# search between two date in access database c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

search between two date in access database c#

Here is the queries I used but Did not show any results:

```
SELECT *
FROM     tbl_daryaft
WHERE  (date1 > '1396/12/1') AND (date1 < '1396/12/25')


SELECT *
FROM     tbl_daryaft
WHERE  (date1 BETWEEN '1396/12/1' AND '1396/12/25')
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Does not show any results Except date 1396/12/24

Comment: Whats `did not answer`

Comment: Did not show any results

Comment: @amir Can you provide the data of your table?

Comment: Where is your c# code?

Comment: View in this image  database Information : [image](https://pasteboard.co/Hc8bnKX.jpg)

Comment: C # code has no problem
If I run a query in Server Explorer in New Query
I will take the same answer

Comment: In Access, dates are delimited by `#` octothorpes. Replace those single quotes with them.